# Access C# nuget package from C++, do I need to use COM?

Tags: c#, c++

I have created a .NET Standard 2.0 nuget package in c# and now I have been asked to make it accessible from C++, which I have not used in over 20 years. I understand a COM object might work, but I have never made one, and I cannot find documentation on how to make one from .NET Standard 2.0. The instructions I have found for .NET Framework mention selecting options I can't find in my project properties. Can I get a link to some documentation, or perhaps there is another way for C++ to access the DLL.

Comment: This might possibly answer my question, but I will need some hours to study it to be sure. I was hoping for something like a how-to.

Comment: The top-rated answer there should only take you a few minutes to figure out.

Comment: The top rated answer shows how to wrap a static method, what if I need to instantiate an object?